# Google API OAuth - getting 401 (Unauthorized) when trying to upload to YouTube

Tags: python, google-api, gdata

The last days I've been banging my head against the wall trying to upload a movie to YouTube using its official Python Wrapper lib.

What I've succeeded till now:

- Building an Request Access URL
- Saving the returned OAuth Secret for a later use (getting the actual Access Token)
- Getting an Access Token and its coupled Secret. Stored them in a DB.

What I'm trying without success:

- Preparing and uploading a video - this always get me a:
  `{'status': 401, 'body': 'Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token.', 'reason': 'Unauthorized'}`

Below is a compilation of the relevant code blocks for the above:

**Getting the Access Request URL**

```
def GetOAuthToken():
    callback_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/media_sites/oauth_access_token_callback/youtube'
    scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com'
    secure = False
    session = True

    yt_service.developer_key = YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY
    yt_service.client_id = YOUTUBE_KEY

    yt_service.SetOAuthInputParameters(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, YOUTUBE_KEY, consumer_secret=YOUTUBE_SECRET)

    req_token = yt_service.FetchOAuthRequestToken(scopes=scope)
    print 'secret: %s' % req_token.secret
    yt_service.SetOAuthToken(req_token)    
    yt_service.SetOAuthToken(req_token)
    return yt_service.GenerateOAuthAuthorizationURL(callback_url=callback_url, )
```

**Getting the Access Token**

```
def handle_token():
    scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com'

    yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    yt_service.developer_key = YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY
    yt_service.client_id = YOUTUBE_KEY

    yt_service.SetOAuthInputParameters(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, YOUTUBE_KEY, consumer_secret=YOUTUBE_SECRET)


    oauth_token = gdata.auth.OAuthTokenFromUrl('http://www.mysite.com/media_sites/oauth_access_token_callback/youtube?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    oauth_token.secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    if oauth_token:
        oauth_token.oauth_input_params = gdata.auth.OAuthInputParams(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, YOUTUBE_KEY, consumer_secret=YOUTUBE_SECRET)
        yt_service.SetOAuthToken(oauth_token)
        access_token = yt_service.UpgradeToOAuthAccessToken()
```

**Uploading The Video**

```
def upload_vid(access_token, access_token_secret):
    my_media_group = gdata.media.Group(
  title=gdata.media.Title(text='My Test Movie'),
  description=gdata.media.Description(description_type='plain',
                                      text='My description'),
  keywords=gdata.media.Keywords(text='cars, funny'),
  category=[gdata.media.Category(
      text='Autos',
      scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat',
      label='Autos')],
  player=None
)


    yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    yt_service.developer_key = YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY
    yt_service.client_id = YOUTUBE_KEY

    yt_service.SetOAuthInputParameters(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, YOUTUBE_KEY, consumer_secret=YOUTUBE_SECRET)

    oauth_token = gdata.auth.OAuthToken(key=access_token, secret=access_token_secret, scopes='http://gdata.youtube.com')
    oauth_token.oauth_input_params = gdata.auth.OAuthInputParams(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, YOUTUBE_KEY, consumer_secret=YOUTUBE_SECRET)

    yt_service.SetOAuthToken(oauth_token)

    where = gdata.geo.Where()
    where.set_location((37.0,-122.0))

    video_entry = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry(media=my_media_group, geo=where)

    video_file_location = '/home/path/of/myfile.flv'

    new_entry = yt_service.InsertVideoEntry(video_entry, video_file_location)
```

So basically this gives me a 401 every time I try to upload a movie.
Any help will be great!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it at the end.
On my case it was sending an escaped token to a method which expect a raw string.

Just make sure you have your token "not escaped" prior to sending them as parameters.

googles OAuth tokens may include a slash which escapes as %2F 
sending such a token will bring you to a 401